# reset fullcalendar event back to external list with eventclick

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How do I reset event that was drag dropped from external event list back into it with event click? Something like remove event and add it back to external event list or just backtrack it or something.

Comment: what have you tried so far? It would help to see how you're doing the dragging as it is. Presumably you need to run code to delete the event, but also re-create a "draggable" element based on the event's data, and append that back into your external list.

Comment: I did it by simply removing event from calendar and showing its the event on external list which was hidden when it was dragged on calendar